# Regret of leaving the opportunity to work on highly funded topics for something not so rewarding. How to stop remorse?

Tags: phd, research-topic, emotional-responses

My materials science PhD group works on two different fields. Most of them work in battery technology while I am few others work in mechanical behavior of materials in aerospace materials.

I was always interested in mechanics of deformation and physics of material behavior (fracture, ballistic impacts and so on). So, when I had to choose a topic for PhD 5 years ago, I went for aerospace topic.

After spending so much time on the topic, though I still love the subject and appreciate how much is still unknown, I have come to a realization that funding is scarce on this field.

In my country of residence, the majority of the funding is provided for battery research, artificial intelligence and cancer research. In my group, the battery research receives huge fundings, while my topic receives constant grant rejections. Alumni from battery topics have gone to MIT and Berkley for their postdoc. While alumni from my field have joined some low ranked university as a postdoc or went to industry.

As I am towards the end of my PhD, I realize this is going to be my future too. I will struggle to get postdoc, tenure track position and subsequent fundings.

Somewhere deep inside, I feel regret for not choosing the battery technology fields. How to stop remorse? Can I get any advice from researcher who have experienced similar struggle in their research careers.

Comment: hindsight is 20/20. Better to focus on now and make the most out of it. You made the best decision based on the information available to you at the time.